# SQL FOREIGN KEY constraint in Insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I've got a problem to insert some values into table.
Microsoft SQL server management shows that:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Players__Menager__55D59338". The conflict occurred in database
>   "TransferyProjekt", table "dbo.Menagers", column 'idMenager'.

My Create table script.

```
CREATE TABLE Menagers (
  idMenager INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [name] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK (name LIKE '[A-Z]%'),
  surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK (surname LIKE '[A-Z]%'),
  phoneNumber VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL CHECK (phoneNumber LIKE '+[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
  PRIMARY KEY (idMenager)
  );

CREATE TABLE Players (
  idPlayer INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [name] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  age DATE NOT NULL check (DATEDIFF(year,age,GETDATE()) > 18),
  club INT NOT NULL,
  Menager INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idPlayer),
  FOREIGN KEY (club) REFERENCES Clubs(idClub),
  FOREIGN KEY (Menager) REFERENCES Menagers(idMenager)
  );
```

My insert look like.

```
INSERT INTO Menagers VALUES
    ('Adil','Green','+232247832'),
    ('Wicky','Dock','+301494064'),
    ('Alead','King','+447499384'),
    ('Darmian','Dagoly','+445587849'),
    ('Kamila','Dobra','+958789278'),
    ('Mateusz','Jankowiak','+849383098'),
    ('Lendy','Day','+448902920'),
    ('Martin','Lloyd','+501044468'),
    ('Adam','Dosh','+045033739'),
    ('Cristian','Cosy','+307748735'),
    ('Andrew','Lloyd','+635875452'),
    ('Matias','Banega','+520091224'),
    ('Carl','Rossi','+196935415'),
    ('Michał','Rolnik','+156541588'),
    ('Denny','Nowsky','+231785387'),
    ('Micky','Elly','+125774609'),
    ('George','Taylor','+094371433'),
    ('Barack','Obama','+916764868'),
    ('Jin','Chan','+906765545'),
    ('Lee','Konsu','+608935829'),
    ('Adam','Kenzo','+417708081'),
    ('Bryan','Along','+939454178'),
    ('Robert','Leey','+183354912'),
    ('Tom','Vardy','+576176145'),
    ('Kevin','Betword','+721582207');

INSERT INTO Players VALUES
        ('Lionel','Messi','1986-07-13','23','4'),
        ('Cristiano','Ronaldo','1986-04-11','23','5'),
        ('Sergio','Ramos','1986-09-07','23','12'),
        ('Łukasz','Piszczek','1986-11-20','23','14'),
        ('Robert','Lewandowski','1986-12-01','2','13'),
        ('Michał','Pazdan','1986-06-01','3','23'),
        ('Łukasz','Trałka','1986-05-02','7','20'),
        ('Łukasz','Teodorczyk','1986-04-14','6','18'),
        ('Mariusz','Miley','1985-03-06','3','26');
```

Comment: mysq or sql server ? both are different

Comment: sql server sorry for mistake

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem your create and load insert work fine for both tables (having removed FOREIGN KEY (club) REFERENCES Clubs(idClub ))

Comment: Do you have Menagers with those ID values? Query that table first and make sure you aren't making an assumption about the IDs that are there. If you've deleted from that table and then re-inserted records, the IDs won't be what you think they are.

Comment: Problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FK column I added unfortunately referece to row who is not exists in table Managers...

> ('Mariusz','Miley','1985-03-06','3','***26***');
>   but I don't have 26'th row in table Managers (Blame me, now) :(

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key and primary key columns are `INT` type. But, you are having following SQL

```
INSERT INTO Players VALUES
    ('Lionel','Messi','1986-07-13','23','4')
```

where last column belongs to foreign key column and your value is string.

Comment: Loads fine for me.Is there some setting which suppresses implicit conversion?

Comment: @P.Salmon But, that's not correct. That might implicitly converted to `0`.

Comment: What's not correct I would expect implicit conversion.

Comment: @P.Salmon So, you are saying you would still try inserting string even you know that expect int ?  But,IMO, I wouldn't. And that is what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @P.Salmon Ravi is right. I see no valid reason to intentionally leave an implicit conversion in it. You know the data types in play, use them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should define column names if your source table and destination table has different column counts or different order

```
INSERT INTO Menagers([name],surname, phoneNumber ) 
VALUES
    ('Adil','Green','+232247832'),
    ('Wicky','Dock','+301494064'),
    ....

INSERT INTO Players([name], surname, age, club, Menager )
VALUES
    ('Lionel','Messi','1986-07-13','23','4'),
    ('Cristiano','Ronaldo','1986-04-11','23','5'),
    ...
```

Comment: It did not solve the problem but I think it is good way to make code clear. Thank for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key is a reference to a unique value in a different table, and SQL will ensure "referential integrity" - which means it won't let you end you with "orphaned" key references. When you insert a value to a foreign key column it must be a null or a existing reference to a row in the other table, and when you delete, you must delete the row containing the foreign key first, then the row it references.

If you don't, you will get an error such as you describe.

So enter the row into the "main" table first, then enter the "dependant" table information second.